# Chances of winning with float percent values smaller 1

Tags: php, random, percentage

I'm building a system that depends on a correct percentage winning chance.  I did not find a single solution that seems to come close, to the chance the percentage indicates.

In my best test, I got between 30%-39% wins on 100k try with a chance of 0.6%. 
(currently, the lowest chance is about 0.025%)

Wouldn't matter to me if the chance would be around 1-3%, but 30%-39%? Here is the code that got closest for now.

```
function randChance($percent){
    $number = 100;
    $percent *= $number;
    while(floor($percent) != $percent){
        $number *= 10;
        $percent *= 10;
    }
    $rates = [$number,$percent];
    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($rates); $i++) {
        $rate = $rates[$i] * 100;
        for ($j = 0; $j <= $rate; $j++) {
            $chance[] = $i;
        }
    }
    shuffle($chance);
    $rnd = mt_rand(0,(count($chance)-1));
    return $chance[$rnd];
}
```

Comment: Why are you shuffling $chance if you're selecting a random key?  shuffle uses very poor randomness.  mt_rand is pretty good, but http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php will likely be the best.

Comment: Also, `count($chance)+1` is likely to present an undefined offset error, I think you want `-1`

Comment: without shuffle the rate is around 40%-50%

Comment: Damn mixed it up with an other function. (changed it). random_int didn't change something on the percentage.

Comment: If you're getting 40-50%, then I'd say that confirms your algorithm is about 50/50 and not really taking chance into the equation.  I haven't had a chance to review your algorithm, just commented on the issues I saw from a quick glance.